# How to do screen record on android without apps?

Tags: video-recording

I want to know  how to do screen recording on Android without apps? I've been trying many apps from Google Play store, but nothing works for me, it's just adds popping up on my phone...

Can anyone show me how can I do it myself, I want to record screen with longer duration (my phone is Samsung Galaxy S4).

Comment: It's not possible without either a special app or a rooted device (and even then a special app as well). Many custom ROMs come bundled with a `screenrecord` binary (may be named differently), too.

Comment: @GiantTree A screen-recording feature was built into Android with Kitkat. So under the condition the device runs Kitkat or higher, your commend no longer holds true. See [Narayanan's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/96258/16575) (and my comment on it) for details.

Comment: `screenrecord` is *sometimes* not bundled with a stock ROM, keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't mentioned the version of Android running in your phone and I assume it is KitKat.

If so, you can use ADB ([Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)) tool to record the video.  The are many blog sites that explain how to do this and one such that came out first on my Google search is [this one](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-record-your-screen-on-android-4-4-kitkat/). Even [Android SDK page on ADB tool commands](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#screenrecord) explain this well.

In gist, you should use these commands:

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4
adb pull /sdcard/demo.mp4
```

The first one starts capturing the screen to the specified file and the second one pulls (copies) the recorded file to your computer.

Update: By the way if you are finding it difficult to download the entire SDK just this small ADB tool, you can use the one from this [XDA page](http://www.xda-developers.com/lightweight-adb-and-fastboot-installer/).

Comment: Also see: [How to use screen recording in Android 4.4 KitKat](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-4-4-kitkat/329674-how-use-screen-recording-android-4-4-kitkat.html) for a more in-depth tutorial on this – and [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) for the ADB part :)