# Screen capture on Android using Android SDK

Tags: video, android-studio

I am trying to take a screen capture of my android phone when it plays a video, with native resolution and minimum overhead. But when I use Android Studio's record option as seen below, the recorded video shows frame drops compared to the actual video seen on the device. I guess it's because device is already at high-performance and can't keep up with this request especially that Android Studio is also showing the video here.

Is there a way to do any better? Can we do it directly with Android SDK through CLI maybe that way there will be less overhead and we'll get a better video recording? Or alternatively, any apps could do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always what you trying to record does depend on what hardware you using and what app(s) you are running on the device at the same time (i.e. play a video). So trying to capture a 1:1 video of the screen in 30/60+ fps may not be possible.

**A.** Using only `adb` you can follow [How to do screen record on android without apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/96258/3573) which while an older answer the Android Developer `adb` page [link](https://developer.android.com/tools/adb#screenrecord) is still valid.

**B.** Similar to Android Studio's screen recording but with more features is [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) which is more general [screen projection/control tool](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207688/3573)

**C.** If you have a device with Android 11 and up you may be able to record directly on the device via a Quick Settings Tile as documented: https://support.google.com/android/answer/9075928

> **Record your phone screen**
>
> 1. Swipe down from the top of your screen.
> 2. Tap Screen record .
>
> - You might need to swipe right to find it.
> - If it's not there, tap Edit and drag Screen record to your Quick Settings.
>
> 3. Choose what you want to record and tap Start. The recording begins after the countdown.
>
> - You can choose whether to record audio and show touches on the screen before you start.
>
> 4. To stop recording, swipe down from the top of the screen and tap the Screen recorder notification

Comment: Oh I didn't notice the phone's screen recorder, option 3. It was good! Tnx.